# Why are there any Innodb_buffer_pool_reads for a small db?

Tags: innodb, mariadb

I have a small DB, < 400MB, using MariaDB 10.4 on a machine with 16GB ram. I've set the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 2G while running some query performance tests.

With the size set to 2G, more than 4x the total size of the DB, why would I get any Innodb_buffer_pool_reads? Why wouldn't all reads be found in the buffer pool?

After a test run I get
  Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests = 280,980,648
  Innodb_buffer_pool_reads = 27,089

I don't mind the hit rate; I'm just wondering if I misunderstand something about the buffer pool.

Comment: The database manager has to read data from somewhere. In your case it's the bufferpool (i.e. memory); what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are counts since the server was started.

The pages must have been read at some stage to get into the buffer pool.

As a test, try a `mysqldump --all-databases --skip-locks` to ensure every row is read. And then look at the `Innodb_buffer_pool_reads`. Then see if this value increases over the next few days.